# Randomly Sample from Every Row of Matrix

Tags: r

Given a 5x5 matrix:

```
dataset=matrix(cbind(c(1,1,2,2,0),
                     c(1,1,2,0,0),
                     c(0,0,0,1,0),
                     c(0,0,1,1,1),
                     c(1,2,3,4,0))
dataset
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    1    0    0    1
[2,]    1    1    0    0    2
[3,]    2    2    0    1    3
[4,]    2    0    1    1    4
[5,]    0    0    0    1    0
```

I want to sample 1 observation from each row of the matrix where the value to be sampled from the row is equal to 1 and I want to create a new matrix that the randomly sampled value is set to `True` in the new matrix and all other values are set to `false`. A sample of the expected output is provided below:

```
       1     2     3     4     5  
1   FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE 
2    TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
3   FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE 
4   FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE 
5   FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Could someone please help me to figure out how I can achieve this.

Comment: Your sample data code is incomplete.

Comment: Your `matrix(` doesn't make sense. Just use `cbind()`

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option

```
# Courtesy of Hadley (avoids the "surprise" sample result when we have only one element)
# [http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/using-quot-sample-quot-for-a-vector-of-length-1-td2299330.html]
resample <- function(x, ...) x[sample.int(length(x), ...)]

set.seed(2019)
t(apply(dataset, 1, function(x) 
    replace(rep(FALSE, length(x)), resample(which(x == 1), 1), TRUE)))
#      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]
#[1,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
#[2,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#[3,] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
#[4,] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
#[5,] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

I've added a fixed random seed for reproducibility; remove to randomly sample `1`s from every row of `dataset`.

---

### Sample data

```
dataset=matrix(
    c(1,1,2,2,0,1,1,2,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,2,3,4,0),
    nrow = 5, ncol = 5)
dataset
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,]    1    1    0    0    1
#[2,]    1    1    0    0    2
#[3,]    2    2    0    1    3
#[4,]    2    0    1    1    4
#[5,]    0    0    0    1    0
```

Comment: @JohnColeman Ah very good and subtle point; thanks I've made a change. I also forget the final transposition.

Comment: I was doing something similar to try to answer the question and ran into that very bug. I didn't know about `resample()` -- good to know about it (although I confess to not completely understanding how it works). Anyways, I deleted my original comment and upvoted.

Comment: Yeah that `sample` quirk had me scratching my hand a while back which is when I came across Hadley's post on the R mailing list. `?sample` calls this a "surprise" example, but I had never stopped to read `?sample` that carefully. Anyway, thanks for the upvote:-)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the request, then this should be an efficient answer:

```
(dataset==1) * rbinom(length(dataset), 1, 0.5)

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    0    0    0    1
[2,]    0    1    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0    1    0
[4,]    0    0    0    1    0
[5,]    0    0    0    1    0
```

My understanding was that you only wanted TRUE (or equyivalently 1) in the same position as the 1's in the original matrix, but only some random sample of those were to be TRUE (or 1)

Comment: I think you need to limit to 1 per row, don't you?

Comment: I guess I do. Not the easiest to understand problem description I've ever read.

Answer (score 1):

I'd approach this by making a big list of all the cells equal to `1`, then just sampling one for each row and updating a copy of the matrix. Like so:

```
idx <- which(dataset==1, arr.ind=TRUE)
idx <- idx[sample(nrow(idx)),]
idx <- idx[!duplicated(idx[,"row"]),]
mat <- matrix(FALSE, nrow=nrow(dataset), ncol=ncol(dataset))
mat[idx] <- TRUE

mat
#      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]
#[1,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#[2,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#[3,] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
#[4,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
#[5,] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

This will scale quite well too. Here's 5 million rows processed in about ~2.5 seconds:

```
dataset <- dataset[rep(1:5,1e6),]
system.time({
idx <- which(dataset==1, arr.ind=TRUE)
idx <- idx[sample(nrow(idx)),]
idx <- idx[!duplicated(idx[,"row"]),]
mat <- matrix(FALSE, nrow=nrow(dataset), ncol=ncol(dataset))
mat[idx] <- TRUE
})
#   user  system elapsed 
#   2.32    0.22    2.58
```